Ошибка при использовании append
Не могу точно понять, где ошибка в коде, поэтому лучше прикреплю полный код:
a=[]
b=[]
minn=0
che=1
b=1
chto=0
while b!=0:
    c=int(input())
    b=c
    if b!=0:
        a.append(b)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]%2!=0 and a[i]>9 and a[i]<100 and a[i]%5!=0 and a[i]%10!=9:
        che*a[i]
        chto=a[i]
        b.append(chto)
    if a[i]%2!=0 and a[i]>999 and a[i]<10000 and a[i]%5!=0 and a[i]%10!=9:
        che*a[i]
        chto=a[i]
        b.append(chto)
b.sort()
minn=b[0]
print(che)
print(minn)


При выполнении кода получаю ошибку:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Подскажите, куда копать?

Строка b=1 приводит к тому, что список b исчезает, появляется целая переменная b.
Используйте другую переменную, имён предостаточно.

Ё, увидел, спасибо

@makilopq, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).

@wchistow Вопрос всё-равно быстро будет закрыт как опечатка, нет особого смысла ответы к нему отмечать
